# Which one is the latest upstream kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I reported a bug on Ubuntu and now the person assigned to me is asking me to test the latest upstream kernel:

> could you please test the latest upstream kernel available from the
>   very top line at the top of the page (the release names are irrelevant
>   for testing, and please do not test the daily folder) following
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds ? It will allow
>   additional upstream developers to examine the issue.

I've installed kernels before and used them, but by "latest upstram kernel", did he mean the latest kernel found on http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D for my particular distro([this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc2-trusty/)) or [this](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.1-rc6-unstable/) one??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean not the latest kernel for Ubuntu distro, but latest kernel released upstream.

I suggest testing 4.0.5 and 4.1rc6.

Officially latest **released** kernel is 4.0.5. But a fix may be found in release candidate.

And you see that they wrote `release names are irrelevant for testing`.